# How can I get Tasker to set my Google Chat Status?

Tags: tasker

I'd like my Google Chat status to update by task; specifically '@Work' and '@Home', on the obvious criteria. Is there a plugin or script that will allow me to set the status in a task? With additional work, could I do it via something like SL4A and trigger it from Tasker? I'd prefer to avoid a graft like this as a plugin would be more efficient, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a plugin! When I first looked, I didn't realize Locale plugins were compatible with Tasker. The plugin is called "[Locale GTalk Plug-in](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.billyfrancisco.localegtalk&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5iaWxseWZyYW5jaXNjby5sb2NhbGVndGFsayJd)" by Billy Francisco. I have a Galaxy Nexus with ICS, and it appears to be working fine; my status was set properly by a Task.

There is a nearly identically named app, "Locale GTalk Plug-in Free" by Willem Stoker; reviews warned it includes Air Push advertising, so I did not install or test it.

Comment: Billy updated his plug in; you can now use %Variables in the text box for setting your status!